# Hibernate validation: give the ability to user to only enter a digits(number) not instead

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a jsf form and I have an input which normally accept only number(integer) .
I want to custom the error message when the user enter a string or char in this field. I want the validation in the data layer thats mean with hibernate annotation. 
I don't want use this default message if the user enter a string instead of integer,  I want using my custom error message.

> : '10S' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example:
>   9346

Please the attached image can explain well.
How could I achieve this please.

[image: image to explain more]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see [hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own javax.validation.MessageInterpolator

(from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-validator-factory-message-interpolator)

> Message interpolators are used by the validation engine to create user
>   readable error messages from constraint message descriptors.
>
> In case the default message interpolation algorithm described in
>   Chapter 4, Interpolating constraint error messages is not sufficient
>   for your needs, you can pass in your own implementation of the
>   MessageInterpolator interface via Configuration#messageInterpolator()

as shown in the example below:

```
package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter09;

public class MyMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator {

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context) {
        //...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale) {
        //...
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can configure your validator to use your custom interpolator like that:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator( new MyMessageInterpolator() )
        .buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

Comment: it looks redundant in this case. Why not use out of the box solution like:

`@NotNull(message = "The manufacturer name must not be null")`

Comment: looks like difficult to implement such custom message

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the @Range annotation

```
@Range(min = -2147483648, max = 2147483647, message= ": '10S' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example: 9346")
long value;
```

Comment: Woops, sorry. I misunderstood the question. I understand what you mean now and I will update my question later on.